# Audio Illusions

Tags: audio-illusion, sound-design, tricks, experimental

So far I have only come across Shepard-Risset Glissando. Does anyone know more audio illusions/tricks which boggle human brain?

Recently I came up with an applied version of Shepard-Risset tone by creating an audio illusion of a sound of a bottle never filling up... Here is the link http://tumblr.com/xrp1pvqqh9 and youtube video
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkXAng5fetk&hd=1

Would like to know if any of you are experimenting with auditory illusions?

Answer (score 4):

Check out "Auditory Scene Analysis" by Al Bregman.

http://webpages.mcgill.ca/staff/Group2/abregm1/web/downloadstoc.htm

Comment: If you're curious, Bregman published a book called Auditory Scene Analysis. (I't s a big fat book, but the last chapter basically sums the whole book up into a digestable length.)

Answer (score 4):

The McGurk effect is a pretty interesting trick.
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McGurk_effect) and [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ypd5txtGdGw)

Comment: awesome...good audio/visual illusion

Answer (score 3):

I know it's not exactly what you're looking for, but I absolutely love the illusion of the "false center" created by a pair of evenly-spaced monitors.

Comment: To that I'd add the Haast Effect and the stereo widening techniques using delay/phase flipping.

Comment: That reminds me, SHEPPi is awesome. (http://dallashodgson.info/articles/OpenAmbienceProject/)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the 'Franssen Effect' aswell!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys... you have put up some good stuff to dig out there. Also this another audiorty illusion called Diana Deutsch's Scale Illusion is quite intriguing. I am planning to do an applied version of the illusion from sound design pespective...worth investigating I feel.